# JMeter: How to save response time taken by each thread in csv

Tags: csv, jmeter, thread-safety

I am checking a load with a minimum of 1000 threads in JMeter in the command line mode. But at the end of the execution, I am getting an aggregated result. What I actually wanted is the time taken for each thread in a CSV or in Graph.

Note: Request and response is in JSON

Answer (score 0):

Please check [simple data writer.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer)
It will help to save the data in csv. From the listener configure, you can control what to capture. From the csv, you can find the time taken per thread.